# How can I upload a YouTube video to Google Drive without it passing through my local device?

Tags: google-drive, youtube

For the purposes of this question, assume the videos are licensed under the GPL.

There is a video on YouTube. I want to save a copy of the video to my Google Drive. Due to data plan considerations, I don't want to first download it to my local device and then upload it. I want everything to happen in the cloud.

I have found some ways to do this, but they were quite complicated. I'm posting this here in the hope of finding more convenient methods.

Comment: You should probably talk about those other methods, otherwise you're likely to have them suggested here as well.

Comment: @AlE. Done. I posted it as an answer. But it's a bit of an inconvenient way, especially when using a phone.

Answer (score 1):

I will post one way to do this. However, it's quite complicated and I'm still very much interested in a more convenient way to do it. (Like a one-click thing, especially one that's easier to do from a phone.)

1. Copy the URL of the video.
2. Paste that URL into [this website.](http://en.savefrom.net/)
3. Right click on the `Download` button and select `Copy Link Address`.
4. Go to [this website](http://ctrlq.org/save/) and sign in to your Google account. The service will ask for permission to manage your Google Drive.
5. When you're taken to a page called `SAVE WEB FILES`, paste the URL you copied in #3.
6. Select Google Drive as destination.
7. Click `Upload file`.
8. Choose which Google Drive folder you want to save the file in.
9. By default this service names all files just `file` without any filetype extension. So you need to give it a `.mp4` (or whatever format you selected in #3) extension in the box at the bottom. For example, you could name it `LOL Cats.mp4`.
10. Click `Save your file`.
11. You will be shown a progress bar. It will often move very quickly, but stay at 99% for a little while (depending on the size of the file.) This is normal. After it's done, you will see a message on the screen. On the bottom of that message, in red, you will see a confirmation of success. You can then go to Google Drive to find your video file.

Comment: This answer no longer works, as the second website shows an error message when you try to grant access to your Google Drive.

Answer (score -2):

You can easily do that with [this site](http://tubedownloadplus.com).
Follow the procedure highlighted by @revetahm

1. Copy the URL of the Video you are watching
2. Paste the copied url in the address bar on [this](http://tubedownloadplus.com)
3. You can then use your favorite downloading tool to get any format mp4, mp3 of available resolution.

Comment: What about the part "without it passing through my local device?"